# Removing options from name "Origin" field of Gramps?

Tags: gramps

Gramps offers a bit of a "stealth" way to add options to its dropdown lists.

I've accidentally added "Suffix" data to the "Origin" field on the person page that I'd like to remove.

I see the option in a .db file but would much prefer to avoid hacking around in the .db if at all possible.

Comment: did you try removing the persons that have the unwanted "Origin" code?

Answer (score 2):

This is a frequently asked question on the Gramps mailing lists and the official answer is always that you have to dump the database to XML and then reload it into a clean database.